# Async Writing to Form from Discord

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, discord

and thank you in advance.

I'm writing an application for my RPG group and have encountered an issue I haven't faced before; communication over the internet. I looked into IRC and have since moved to Discord. I've got it to were I can write messages to Discord from my application. But I can't receive messages from Discord and write them to the RTB in my application. I'm curious how to resolve this issue; any help would be appreciated. I'm getting an error stating I need a suitable GetAwaiter method for the String type.

```
Private Async Function On_Input(Message As SocketMessage) As Task

    Dim Parameter_00 As String = Input_01.Text      'Bot Name
    Dim Parameter_01 As String = Input_02.Text      'Channel Name

    If Message.Author.Username <> Parameter_00 And Message.Channel.Name = Parameter_01.ToLower Then
        Await Output_00.Text &= vbNewLine & Message.Content
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: The contents of your `If` block doesn't make sense. You would need an async method that updates that control that you can await. You might also look at `Task.Run`. Basically, you need to do some more research on `Async`/`Await` because your current understanding obviously has some holes.

Comment: Ok. My current understanding of Async/Await is a healthy 0%.